# Find which direction headed using geo-points

Tags: android, geolocation, compass-geolocation

Is it possible to make a compass-like using two geo-points?
So regardless of how my phone is positioned, I want to find which direction I moved (like NW) in real-world coordinate system. In other words, my phone is facing to the west in the real-world, but I am heading to the North-West and I want to find that I am heading to the North-West using two geo-points, or possible others but not a magnetic field.
Thanks!

Comment: Sure, possible that's what all the car navigation apps do. It's just a bit complicated to calculate it. http://www.compassdude.com/latitude-longitude.shtml has some basic info, http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html has some formulas